# How do I use catchError() and still return a typed Observable with rxJs 6.0?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, rxjs6

cdSo I'm trying to migrate some of my Angular 5 code to 6, and I understand most of the changes required for rxjs to work using the .pipe() operator. It works as you would expect for 'pipable' operations.

However, the behavior of `catchError()` is different than the `.catch()` operator. Prior to rxjs 6 I used the `.catch()` operator to transform the error input into a a consistent error object that can then be caught in the `.subscribe().

```
getAlbums(): Observable<Album[]> {
     return this.httpClient.get<Album[]>(this.config.urls.url("albums"))
           .map(albumList => this.albumList = albumList)
           .catch(new ErrorInfo().parseObservableResponseError);            
    }
```

`new ErrorInfo().parseObservableResponseError` is a function that takes a error object as input and parses the input error into a simpler error object with a normalized object. Catch returns `Observable<any>`:

```
parseObservableResponseError(response): Observable<any> {
    let err = new ErrorInfo();
    ...
    return Observable.throw(err);        
}
```

This worked great for easily handling errors up rxjs5 - errors basically are captured as part of the pipeline and then throw a well known error structure that can be captured `.subscribe()` error function.

Moving that same code to rxjs 6 however and using `.pipe()` I am trying to do the following:

```
getAlbums(): Observable<Album[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Album[]>(this.config.urls.url("albums"))
                .pipe(
                    map(albumList => this.albumList = albumList),
                    catchError(new ErrorInfo().parseObservableResponseError)                        
                );           
}
```

However this doesn't work because catchError now returns a result of `Observable<any>` into the pipeline, which is not what I want here. In essence I just want to re-throw any errors as I did before.

> error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{} | Album[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'

How do simulate the old  operator `.catch()`behavior?

**Update:**

After mucking around with this a bit more, the code as shown just started working without giving me a build error. Honestly I have no idea why it failed with the error message before, but is working now. The suggestion by @cartant in the comments is an explicit way to specify the result and that works as well.

Comment: What if you just throw the new ErrorInfo(). parseObservableResponseError(e) instead of returning it?

Comment: why not catchError((e:any)=>{ return Observable.of({ success: false, error: true }));? or catchError((e:any)=>{ return Observable.throw(e.error)}))

Comment: @Eliseo this can occasionally work, but the primary problem is you then get a return type that is a union of the observable's original type (might be HttpResponse) and this 'success/fail' structure. i.e if you continue with the chain you'd have `HttpResponse | { success: boolean, error: any }`. You'd then need to add an additional 'map' after it to normalize the type. I've tried this and it's a huge pain. The point of catchError is that it isn't called if there's no error!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be able to explicitly specify the type parameters to `catchError` to indicate that it won't return an observable that emits a value - that is, it will return `Observable<never>` - and will always throw:

```
getAlbums(): Observable<Album[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Album[]>(this.config.urls.url("albums"))
        .pipe(
            map(albumList => this.albumList = albumList),
            catchError<Album[], never>(new ErrorInfo().parseObservableResponseError)
        );           
}
```

Doing so will see the type inferred from the `pipe` call to be `Observable<Album[]>`.

Comment: `catchError` should really have an overload signature so that the correct result is inferred if the passed function's return type is `never` - i.e. always throws. Time to create another PR, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You can return a typed observable with:

```
return of (new YourType({ }));
```

instead of

```
return throwError(()=>err);
```

For example:

```
http.get<CustomType>().pipe(
  map(result=>{
    // do something here, such as accessing local storage, stopping a spinner...etc.
    return result;
  }),
  catchError(err => {
     return of (new CustomType({
 //initialization with a constructor
}));
    // or you can return throwError(err);
  })
)
```